# What is the maximum number of phone numbers per one contact in Gmail?

Tags: google-contacts

Does anyone know what is the limit for number of phone numbers (any type) I can add to one single contact in Gmail? There's information online regarding the maximum number of contacts you can have, but I couldn't find anything about a limit to the number of phone numbers per one contact.

Comment: Why do you need to know this limit? Will you add the numbers manually or  by other means? Are you planning to sync your contacts with other apps link addressbook of a mobile device?

Answer (score 5):

According to [Google support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/148779) a contact can have up to 500 fields. I just tested this by creating a CSV file with the following fields (which seem to be required for it to import):

- Name
- Family Name
- Notes
- Group Membership

I then added 499 Phone pairs in this format:

- Phone 1 - Type
- Phone 1 - Value

... up to:

- Phone 499 - Type
- Phone 499 - Value

For a grand total of 1002 fields in the CSV file (because each phone number has two CSV entries, but counts as one field). Apparently the Name and Family Name count as one field, and Notes and Group Membership don't count toward the total.

I was unable to add any more fields, like Email through the site, so I think I really did hit the hard limit. I also am unable to import a file with 500 phone numbers, but there was no error; it just didn't do anything.

So, the limit is 499 phone numbers and a name.

EDIT:
After further testing, I've found that even though you can put in 499 phone numbers, it isn't really a good idea. The contact I created actually prevented me from syncing my contacts to both of my Android phones. Because I actually do need a contact with 499 phone numbers, I ended up creating two contacts, with different name suffixes, each with 250 phone numbers. Those sync to Android and display fine for me.